# ReleaseMutex fails in single-thread c# windows forms app

Tags: c#, winforms, mutex

I've looked through SO for this issue, but the other instances seem to relate only to multi-threaded app issues.

My app is a straightforward single-form, single-thread app and I'm just using a mutex to ensure only one instance is run on the host system.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace UPGRADE
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Mutex mSpartacus;

            Assembly myAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            GuidAttribute ga = (GuidAttribute)myAssembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(GuidAttribute), false).GetValue(0);
            string sMyGUID = ga.Value.ToString().ToUpper();
            string sMutexId = @"Global\{" + sMyGUID + @"}";

            bool bMutexAcquired = false;
            mSpartacus = new Mutex(false, sMutexId, out bMutexAcquired);
            if (!bMutexAcquired)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Upgrade.exe is already running.\n\nOnly one instance can run at once.", "Already running");
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                Form1 myForm = new Form1();
                Application.Run(myForm);
            }
            finally
            {
                mSpartacus.ReleaseMutex();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It fails on the ReleaseMutex() call with the error *Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code.*

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong? The mutex was originally a static variable, but putting it inside the Main() function didn't stop the error occurring.

Answer (score 5):

As read from the msdn, you should pass `true` on the `initiallyOwned` parameter.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwe34f1k(v=vs.110).aspx

```
mSpartacus = new Mutex(true, sMutexId, out bMutexAcquired);
```

Because the first instance of the application wants to have the ownership (so other instances of the same program, can't have it). If you don't have the ownership, you can't release it. If you can't have the ownership, because another instance is already acquired it, the `bMutexAcquired` returns false.

---

If you pass `false` to the `initiallyOwned` parameter. You are only creating the mutex. Then you must use `WaitOne()` to acquire (lock) the mutex and `ReleaseMutex()` to release it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to acquire the `Mutex`. There are two way to acquire the Mutex:

- Using `WaitOne` method
- Using the constructor argument `initiallyOwned`

Here's an example using the `WaitOne` method:

```
const string AppId = "Global\\1DDFB948-19F1-417C-903D-BE05335DB8A4"; // Unique per application 
static void Main(string[] args) 
{ 
   using (Mutex mutex = new Mutex(false, AppId)) 
   { 
       if (!mutex.WaitOne(0)) 
       { 
           Console.WriteLine("2nd instance"); 
           return; 
       } 
       Console.WriteLine("Started"); 
       Console.ReadKey(); 
   } 
}
```